# HBase Shell - scan table filter by column contains string

Tags: apache, hbase, hbase-shell

Is it possible to search for a record in hbase shell by searching for a string inside of a column?

For instance, let's say my hbase table has a key "1" with column "col1" and the value is "something something yeah yeah hey what yup"

i want to return all records in my table where col1 contains the string "hey".

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3):

You can use SingleColumnValueFilter and RegEx.

```
scan 'tableName', {FILTER=>"SingleColumnValueFilter ('column family','col1',=,'regexstring:.*hey.*')"}
```